# Emacs "strongly read-only" text: No highlight, no cursor access

Tags: emacs, readonly

I would like to make a column on the left side of the buffer "strongly read-only". The cursor should not be able to go there. A multi-line highlight should skip the column. Text search should skip the column. Etc.

Is it possible?

Each row of the column carries information about the corresponding line of the original buffer. I considered making the column into a separate vertical buffer, but then I would have to worry about keeping them in vertical sync.

I imagine including the column of predecessor counts in the text buffer, as ordinary text. If I did that, I would have to rewrite a lot of commands (cursor movement, highlight, text search, ...) to ignore the column.

I found how to [make a region "weakly read-only"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76531/emacs-make-portion-of-buffer-readonly), such that it can be copied and searched, just not edited.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty big project -- so I would hope you plan to be using it a lot once the library is fully implemented.  Missing from the outline for this new library is whether the variable `truncate-lines` is set to `t`; and, what should happen when you press the return key or attempt to delete a line or or just delete a `\n`.  My initial thought would be to draw a line with something like `vline.el` and then brainstorm from there.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just want to use the *margin*.  Look it up in the Emacs Lisp manual `(info "(elisp)Display Margins")`.  Or check `C-h o set-window-margins RET` and the documentation of the `display` text-property.

Answer (score 0):

What if one buffer was just a view of two others?